# Recalculating chainage values from a parallel line

Tags: field-calculator, polyline-creation, qchainage

I am currently trying to recalculate the chainage value of one line in contrast with another parallel line.
[image: example]

I have two polylines layers and their corresponding chainage (two layers in point geometric type).

In the example, as a result, the chainage with the label "58.44" must be updated with the equivalent value (measured perpendicularly) of the parallel line."73.497"

[image]

I am looking for suggestions to do this in one go for each chainage point.